# ADF faces: Expose an URL which calls a managed bean

Tags: servlets, javabeans, oracle-adf

In ADF I'm trying to expose an URL https://myapp.com/mywar/logout so my application will make a call to the managed bean 'MyBean' and then forward the request.

1. I've tried with a simple servlet, but cannot get an instance of 'MyBean'. I have tried this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Access+FacesContext+From+Servlet but I can't get the facesContext - it is just null. Perhaps this is not the right way anyway.
2. Then I'm trying to do this in a "faces context" with an URL like https://myapp.com/mywar/faces/logout. Creating an .jspx page just seems inappropriate to me, because there is nothing to display - just a method call and a forward.

Any other simple way of doing this?

Comment: Create and call a servlet?

Comment: I've tried with a servlet, but cannot get an instance of a managed bean I need.

Comment: What data/logic does you managed bean contain?

Answer (score 0):

Create an URL accessible TaskFlow and set the default Activity to a MethodCall that points to the method you want in the ManagedBean.

Comment: Hi Rafael, could you please elaborate a bit on this? I'm new to ADF. I can create a new Bounded Task, but how do I make it URL accessible, and how do I point to the method in my bean (like this <default-activity>myBean.myMethod</default-activity>)?